# Mysql view with join multiple table results in slow query

Tags: mysql, join, view

I am currently working on creating a view which will join multiple tables. I can get the result by using left join, but the query loads very slow. I have also tried using Inner Join, but not showing any result. Is there anyway to make my query fast?
Below are the code :

```
CREATE 
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
DEFINER = `root`@`%` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `prc`.`vsrparts_latest` AS
SELECT 
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`SRPartsID` AS `SRPartsID`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`RepairID` AS `RepairID`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`SRNo` AS `SRNo`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`DateReceived` AS `DateReceived`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`ShipmentDate` AS `ShipmentDate`,
    `prc`.`tbparts`.`PartsNo` AS `PartsNo`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`PartID` AS `PartID`,
    `prc`.`tbparts`.`PartsDesc` AS `PartsDesc`,
    `prc`.`tbcompany`.`Company` AS `Company`,
    `prc`.`tbcompany`.`Alias` AS `Alias`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`RepairCenter` AS `RepairCenter`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`UserID` AS `UserID`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`NinetyDaysReturn` AS `NinetyDaysReturn`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`PartSN` AS `PartSN`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`RefurbishedSN` AS `RefurbishedSN`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`CountFrequency` AS `CountFrequency`,
    `prc`.`tbuser`.`EmployeeID` AS `EmployeeID`,
    `vpartsinfo`.`PartsNo` AS `FinalPart`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`FinalPart` AS `FinalPartID`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`EcoImplemented` AS `EcoImplemented`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`VisualInspectionStatus` AS `VisualInspectionStatus`,
    `prc`.`tbvisual`.`VisualInspectionErrorCode` AS `VisualInspectionErrorCode`,
    `prc`.`tbvisual`.`VisualInspectionActionTaken` AS `VisualInspectionActionTaken`,
    `prc`.`tbvisual`.`VisualInspectionComponentLocation` AS `VisualInspectionComponentLocation`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`VisualInspectionResult` AS `VisualInspectionResult`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`DebugTestingStatus` AS `DebugTestingStatus`,
    `prc`.`tb1stdebug`.`FirstDebugTestingErrorCode` AS `FirstDebugTestingErrorCode`,
    `prc`.`tb1stdebug`.`FirstDebugActionTaken` AS `FirstDebugActionTaken`,
    `prc`.`tb1stdebug`.`FirstDebugComponentLocation` AS `FirstDebugComponentLocation`,
    `prc`.`tb2nddebug`.`SecondDebugTestingErrorCode` AS `SecondDebugTestingErrorCode`,
    `prc`.`tb2nddebug`.`SecondDebugActionTaken` AS `SecondDebugActionTaken`,
    `prc`.`tb2nddebug`.`SecondDebugComponentLocation` AS `SecondDebugComponentLocation`,
    `prc`.`tb3rddebug`.`ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode` AS `ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode`,
    `prc`.`tb3rddebug`.`ThirdDebugActionTaken` AS `ThirdDebugActionTaken`,
    `prc`.`tb3rddebug`.`ThirdDebugComponentLocation` AS `ThirdDebugComponentLocation`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`DebugTestingResult` AS `DebugTestingResult`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`FctTestingStatus` AS `FctTestingStatus`,
    `prc`.`tb1stfct`.`FirstFctTestingErrorCode` AS `FirstFctTestingErrorCode`,
    `prc`.`tb1stfct`.`FirstFctActionTaken` AS `FirstFctActionTaken`,
    `prc`.`tb1stfct`.`FirstFctComponentLocation` AS `FirstFctComponentLocation`,
    `prc`.`tb2ndfct`.`SecondFctTestingErrorCode` AS `SecondFctTestingErrorCode`,
    `prc`.`tb2ndfct`.`SecondFctActionTaken` AS `SecondFctActionTaken`,
    `prc`.`tb2ndfct`.`SecondFctComponentLocation` AS `SecondFctComponentLocation`,
    `prc`.`tb3rdfct`.`ThirdFctTestingErrorCode` AS `ThirdFctTestingErrorCode`,
    `prc`.`tb3rdfct`.`ThirdFctActionTaken` AS `ThirdFctActionTaken`,
    `prc`.`tb3rdfct`.`ThirdFctComponentLocation` AS `ThirdFctComponentLocation`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`FctTestingResult` AS `FctTestingResult`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`RelayFailure` AS `RelayFailure`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`RelayDateCode` AS `RelayDateCode`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`DefectiveRelayColor` AS `DefectiveRelayColor`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`RelayFailureLocation` AS `RelayFailureLocation`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`DateCreated` AS `DateCreated`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`LastUpdated` AS `LastUpdated`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`EstimatedRepairCompletionDate` AS `EstimatedRepairCompletionDate`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`StartRepairDate` AS `StartRepairDate`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`Status` AS `Status`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`AttachmentName` AS `AttachmentName`,
    `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`PartsReturnProcess` AS `PartsReturnProcess`,
    (TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) - TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(`prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`DateReceived`,
                        ',',
                        '-'),
                    '%d-%M-%Y'))) AS `dateNew`
FROM
    (((((((((((`prc`.`tbsrparts_new`
    JOIN `prc`.`tbparts` ON ((`prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`PartID` = `prc`.`tbparts`.`PartsID`)))
    JOIN `prc`.`tbcompany` ON ((`prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`RepairCenter` = `prc`.`tbcompany`.`CompanyID`)))
    JOIN `prc`.`vpartsinfo` ON ((`vpartsinfo`.`PartsID` = `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`FinalPart`)))
    JOIN `prc`.`tbuser` ON ((`prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`UserID` = `prc`.`tbuser`.`UserID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `prc`.`tbvisual` ON ((`prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`RepairID` = `prc`.`tbvisual`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `prc`.`tb1stdebug` ON ((`prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`RepairID` = `prc`.`tb1stdebug`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `prc`.`tb2nddebug` ON ((`prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`RepairID` = `prc`.`tb2nddebug`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `prc`.`tb3rddebug` ON ((`prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`RepairID` = `prc`.`tb3rddebug`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `prc`.`tb1stfct` ON ((`prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`RepairID` = `prc`.`tb1stfct`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `prc`.`tb2ndfct` ON ((`prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`RepairID` = `prc`.`tb2ndfct`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `prc`.`tb3rdfct` ON ((`prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`RepairID` = `prc`.`tb3rdfct`.`RepairID`)))
ORDER BY `prc`.`tbsrparts_new`.`SRPartsID` DESC
```

Below are the schema of tables :

### **tbsrparts_new**

```
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|             Field             |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SRPartsID                     | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                      | varchar(200)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| SRNo                          | varchar(200)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| DateReceived                  | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ShipmentDate                  | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| NinetyDaysReturn              | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PartID                        | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PartSN                        | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| RefurbishedSN                 | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FinalPart                     | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| DefectPart                    | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| RelayFailure                  | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| RelayDateCode                 | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| DefectiveRelayColor           | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| RelayFailureLocation          | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| RepairCenter                  | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| UserID                        | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| DateCreated                   | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LastUpdated                   | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LastUpdatedBy                 | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EstimatedRepairCompletionDate | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| StartRepairDate               | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Attachment                    | longblob           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| AttachmentName                | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| AttachmentType                | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| AttachmentSize                | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PartsReturnProcess            | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EcoImplemented                | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CountFrequency                | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| VisualInspectionStatus        | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| VisualInspectionResult        | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| DebugTestingStatus            | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| DebugTestingResult            | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ICTTestingStatus              | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ICTTestingResult              | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ICTTestingErrorCode           | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ICTTestingActionTaken         | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ICTTestingComponentLocation   | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ICTTestingDesignator          | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FctTestingStatus              | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FctTestingResult              | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Status                        | varchar(40)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tbuser**

```
+---------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|     Field     |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+---------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| UserID        | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Username      | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Password      | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Name          | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EmployeeID    | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Email         | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| StatusID      | "int(10) unsigned" | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| AuthorityID   | "int(10) unsigned" | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CompanyID     | "int(10) unsigned" | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LastUpdated   | varchar(50)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LastUpdatedBy | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LastLogin     | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | N/A     |                |
+---------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tbparts**

```
+-----------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|      Field      |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| PartsID         | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| PartsNo         | varchar(20)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| PartsDesc       | varchar(100)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CompanyID       | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| UserID          | "int(10) unsigned" | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LastUpdatedTime | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Category        | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tbcompany**

```
+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|    Field     |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| CompanyID    | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Company      | varchar(45)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Alias        | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SupplierCode | varchar(45)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **vpartsinfo**

```
+-----------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
|      Field      |        Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| PartsID         | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| PartsNo         | varchar(20)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| PartsDesc       | varchar(100)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CompanyID       | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| UserID          | "int(10) unsigned" | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LastUpdatedTime | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Company         | varchar(45)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Name            | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

### **tb1stdebug**

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|            Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| FirstDebugID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                    | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstDebugTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| FirstDebugActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstDebugComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tb2nddebug**

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|            Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SecondDebugID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                     | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SecondDebugTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SecondDebugActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SecondDebugComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tb3rddebug**

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|            Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ThirdDebugID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                    | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ThirdDebugActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ThirdDebugComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tb1stfct**

```
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|           Field           |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| FirstFctID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                  | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstFctTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| FirstFctActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstFctComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tb2ndfct**

```
+----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|           Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SecondFctID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                   | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SecondFctTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SecondFctActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SecondFctComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tb3rdfct**

```
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|           Field           |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ThirdFctID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                  | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ThirdFctTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ThirdFctActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ThirdFctComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tbvisual**

```
+-----------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|               Field               |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| VisualID                          | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                          | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| VisualInspectionErrorCode         | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| VisualInspectionActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| VisualInspectionComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: @DrewPierce, I have already create indexes for all the columns. Still slow.

Comment: Hi @DrewPierce, any way to make it fast? can u advise me?

Comment: @DrewPierce, i have pasted the table schema related to the query. Hope u can help me.

Comment: Great we will take a look

Comment: Hi @DrewPierce, can you suggest me any solution?

Comment: Is there a reason for the 11 nests that you have at the bottom with (((((((etc? Also how many rows are in the tables (the biggest ones rowcount-wise)

Comment: And how long does it take? How often is it run?

Comment: The 11 nest is because its joins 11 tables. The rows is about 25K.
I takes about 726 seconds and will run if the users click the link on our page.

Comment: I was afraid the nests were necessary. Working on it. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A) First run `explain select [the whole select and join]` and save output somewhere.

(B) I count 14 missing indexes which I denoted as **MISS** in the Key column from your tables below. You are doing table scans and not using indexes despite a primary key in table.

In your From clause you can see 19 **NO** comments to the far right. But in reality there are 14 total missing

(C) Consider creating all 14 missing keys (naturally this slows down inserts).

```
alter table tbsrparts_new add index(RepairID);
alter table tbsrparts_new add index(PartID);
alter table tbsrparts_new add index(FinalPart);
alter table tbsrparts_new add index(DefectPart);
alter table tbsrparts_new add index(RepairCenter);
alter table tbsrparts_new add index(UserID);
alter table vpartsinfo add index(PartsID);
alter table tb1stdebug add index(RepairID);
alter table tb2nddebug add index(RepairID);
alter table tb3rddebug add index(RepairID);
alter table tb1stfct add index(RepairID);
alter table tb2ndfct add index(RepairID);
alter table tb3rdfct add index(RepairID);
alter table tbvisual add index(RepairID);
```

(D) Run `explain select [the whole select and join]` and save output somewhere.

(E) Share results of (A) and (D) with the Question so someone can help you if you need further help.

(F) When happy create your view.

**Good Luck !**

```
SELECT 
    new.SRPartsID AS SRPartsID,
    new.RepairID AS RepairID,
    new.SRNo AS SRNo,
    new.DateReceived AS DateReceived,
    new.ShipmentDate AS ShipmentDate,
    tbparts.PartsNo AS PartsNo,
    new.PartID AS PartID,
    tbparts.PartsDesc AS PartsDesc,
    tbcompany.Company AS Company,
    tbcompany.Alias AS Alias,
    new.RepairCenter AS RepairCenter,
    new.UserID AS UserID,
    new.NinetyDaysReturn AS NinetyDaysReturn,
    new.PartSN AS PartSN,
    new.RefurbishedSN AS RefurbishedSN,
    new.CountFrequency AS CountFrequency,
    tbuser.EmployeeID AS EmployeeID,
    vpartsinfo.PartsNo AS FinalPart,
    new.FinalPart AS FinalPartID,
    new.EcoImplemented AS EcoImplemented,
    new.VisualInspectionStatus AS VisualInspectionStatus,
    tbvisual.VisualInspectionErrorCode AS VisualInspectionErrorCode,
    tbvisual.VisualInspectionActionTaken AS VisualInspectionActionTaken,
    tbvisual.VisualInspectionComponentLocation AS VisualInspectionComponentLocation,
    new.VisualInspectionResult AS VisualInspectionResult,
    new.DebugTestingStatus AS DebugTestingStatus,
    prc.tb1stdebug.FirstDebugTestingErrorCode AS FirstDebugTestingErrorCode,
    prc.tb1stdebug.FirstDebugActionTaken AS FirstDebugActionTaken,
    prc.tb1stdebug.FirstDebugComponentLocation AS FirstDebugComponentLocation,
    prc.tb2nddebug.SecondDebugTestingErrorCode AS SecondDebugTestingErrorCode,
    prc.tb2nddebug.SecondDebugActionTaken AS SecondDebugActionTaken,
    prc.tb2nddebug.SecondDebugComponentLocation AS SecondDebugComponentLocation,
    prc.tb3rddebug.ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode AS ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode,
    prc.tb3rddebug.ThirdDebugActionTaken AS ThirdDebugActionTaken,
    prc.tb3rddebug.ThirdDebugComponentLocation AS ThirdDebugComponentLocation,
    new.DebugTestingResult AS DebugTestingResult,
    new.FctTestingStatus AS FctTestingStatus,
    tb1stfct.FirstFctTestingErrorCode AS FirstFctTestingErrorCode,
    tb1stfct.FirstFctActionTaken AS FirstFctActionTaken,
    tb1stfct.FirstFctComponentLocation AS FirstFctComponentLocation,
    tb2ndfct.SecondFctTestingErrorCode AS SecondFctTestingErrorCode,
    tb2ndfct.SecondFctActionTaken AS SecondFctActionTaken,
    tb2ndfct.SecondFctComponentLocation AS SecondFctComponentLocation,
    tb3rdfct.ThirdFctTestingErrorCode AS ThirdFctTestingErrorCode,
    tb3rdfct.ThirdFctActionTaken AS ThirdFctActionTaken,
    tb3rdfct.ThirdFctComponentLocation AS ThirdFctComponentLocation,
    new.FctTestingResult AS FctTestingResult,
    new.RelayFailure AS RelayFailure,
    new.RelayDateCode AS RelayDateCode,
    new.DefectiveRelayColor AS DefectiveRelayColor,
    new.RelayFailureLocation AS RelayFailureLocation,
    new.DateCreated AS DateCreated,
    new.LastUpdated AS LastUpdated,
    new.EstimatedRepairCompletionDate AS EstimatedRepairCompletionDate,
    new.StartRepairDate AS StartRepairDate,
    new.Status AS Status,
    new.AttachmentName AS AttachmentName,
    new.PartsReturnProcess AS PartsReturnProcess,
    (TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) - TO_DAYS(STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(new.DateReceived,
                        ',',
                        '-'),
                    '%d-%M-%Y'))) AS dateNew
FROM
    tbsrparts_new new
    JOIN tbparts ON tbsrparts_new.PartID=tbparts.PartsId    -- indexes there: **NO**, Yes
    JOIN tbcompany ON tbsrparts_new.RepairCenter = tbcompany.CompanyID -- indexes there: **NO** , Yes
    JOIN vpartsinfo ON vpartsinfo.PartsID = new.FinalPart -- indexes there: **NO**, **NO**

    JOIN tbuser ON new.UserID = tbuser.UserID -- indexes there: **NO**, Yes
    LEFT JOIN tbvisual ON new.RepairID = tbvisual.RepairID -- indexes there: **NO**, **NO**
    LEFT JOIN tb1stdebug ON new.RepairID = tb1stdebug.RepairID -- indexes there: **NO**, **NO**

    LEFT JOIN tb2nddebug ON new.RepairID = tb2nddebug.RepairID -- indexes there: **NO**, **NO**
    LEFT JOIN tb3rddebug ON new.RepairID = tb3rddebug.RepairID -- indexes there: **NO**, **NO**
    LEFT JOIN tb1stfct ON new.RepairID = tb1stfct.RepairID -- indexes there: **NO**, **NO**

    LEFT JOIN tb2ndfct ON new.RepairID = tb2ndfct.RepairID -- indexes there: **NO**, **NO**
    LEFT JOIN tb3rdfct ON new.RepairID = tb3rdfct.RepairID -- indexes there: **NO**, **NO**
ORDER BY new.SRPartsID DESC
```

Below is schema of related tables. Note my comment (B) at beginning of answer:

### **tbsrparts_new**

```
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|             Field             |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SRPartsID                     | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                      | varchar(200)       | NO   |MISS | NULL    |                |
| SRNo                          | varchar(200)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| DateReceived                  | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ShipmentDate                  | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| NinetyDaysReturn              | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PartID                        | varchar(200)       | YES  |MISS | NULL    |                |
| PartSN                        | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| RefurbishedSN                 | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FinalPart                     | varchar(200)       | YES  |MISS | NULL    |                |
| DefectPart                    | varchar(200)       | YES  |MISS | NULL    |                |
| RelayFailure                  | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| RelayDateCode                 | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| DefectiveRelayColor           | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| RelayFailureLocation          | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| RepairCenter                  | varchar(200)       | YES  |MISS | NULL    |                |
| UserID                        | varchar(200)       | YES  |MISS | NULL    |                |
| DateCreated                   | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LastUpdated                   | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LastUpdatedBy                 | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EstimatedRepairCompletionDate | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| StartRepairDate               | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Attachment                    | longblob           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| AttachmentName                | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| AttachmentType                | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| AttachmentSize                | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PartsReturnProcess            | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EcoImplemented                | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CountFrequency                | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| VisualInspectionStatus        | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| VisualInspectionResult        | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| DebugTestingStatus            | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| DebugTestingResult            | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ICTTestingStatus              | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ICTTestingResult              | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ICTTestingErrorCode           | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ICTTestingActionTaken         | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ICTTestingComponentLocation   | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ICTTestingDesignator          | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FctTestingStatus              | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FctTestingResult              | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Status                        | varchar(40)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tbuser**

```
+---------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|     Field     |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+---------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| UserID        | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Username      | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Password      | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Name          | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EmployeeID    | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Email         | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| StatusID      | "int(10) unsigned" | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| AuthorityID   | "int(10) unsigned" | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CompanyID     | "int(10) unsigned" | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LastUpdated   | varchar(50)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LastUpdatedBy | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LastLogin     | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | N/A     |                |
+---------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tbparts**

```
+-----------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|      Field      |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| PartsID         | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| PartsNo         | varchar(20)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| PartsDesc       | varchar(100)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CompanyID       | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| UserID          | "int(10) unsigned" | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| LastUpdatedTime | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Category        | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tbcompany**

```
+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|    Field     |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| CompanyID    | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Company      | varchar(45)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Alias        | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SupplierCode | varchar(45)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **vpartsinfo**

```
+-----------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
|      Field      |        Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| PartsID         | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   |MISS | 0       |       |
| PartsNo         | varchar(20)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| PartsDesc       | varchar(100)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CompanyID       | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| UserID          | "int(10) unsigned" | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LastUpdatedTime | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Company         | varchar(45)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Name            | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

### **tb1stdebug**

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|            Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| FirstDebugID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                    | varchar(500)       | YES  |MISS | NULL    |                |
| FirstDebugTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| FirstDebugActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstDebugComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tb2nddebug**

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|            Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SecondDebugID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                     | varchar(500)       | YES  |MISS | NULL    |                |
| SecondDebugTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SecondDebugActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SecondDebugComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tb3rddebug**

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|            Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ThirdDebugID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                    | varchar(500)       | YES  |MISS | NULL    |                |
| ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ThirdDebugActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ThirdDebugComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tb1stfct**

```
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|           Field           |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| FirstFctID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                  | varchar(45)        | YES  |MISS | NULL    |                |
| FirstFctTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| FirstFctActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstFctComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tb2ndfct**

```
+----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|           Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SecondFctID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                   | varchar(45)        | YES  |MISS | NULL    |                |
| SecondFctTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SecondFctActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SecondFctComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tb3rdfct**

```
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|           Field           |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ThirdFctID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                  | varchar(45)        | YES  |MISS | NULL    |                |
| ThirdFctTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ThirdFctActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ThirdFctComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### **tbvisual**

```
+-----------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|               Field               |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| VisualID                          | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                          | varchar(45)        | YES  |MISS | NULL    |                |
| VisualInspectionErrorCode         | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| VisualInspectionActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| VisualInspectionComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As a side issue attempting to solve excess data appearing unrelated to index optimization:

A) Output

```
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| FirstDebugTestingErrorCode | SecondDebugTestingErrorCode | ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| T00111                     | T03333                      | T05555                     |
| T00111                     | T03333                      | T06666                     |
| T00111                     | T04444                      | T05555                     |
| T00111                     | T04444                      | T06666                     |
| T02222                     | T03333                      | T05555                     |
| T02222                     | T03333                      | T06666                     |
| T02222                     | T04444                      | T05555                     |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

B) Desired Output

```
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| FirstDebugTestingErrorCode | SecondDebugTestingErrorCode | ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| T00111                     | T04444                      | T06666                     |
| T02222                     | T03333                      | T05555                     |
+----------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: After I add the indexes it become fast. Thanks for your help sir!

Comment: Hi Drew, Is there any way to prevent duplicate data on this view?
After we add more datas, its showing a lot of duplicates record on the view.

Comment: How about `select distinct ` then the rest?

Comment: I tried, its still showing the same amount. Lets say i add 2 records on the tb1stdebug that refer to RepairID 1, then i should show 2 rows on the view with different tb1stdebug data as i add before. Is there any way?

Comment: You have so many columns. Can you (A) show 2 or 3 rows as output (not all columns maybe 5) and then (B) show desired out for same?

Comment: I have add A and B on your answer at below. I can add it in the comment,
Can you try to hava a look.

Comment: Took a look. I don't see any duplicate data in the 7 rows (that you arbitrarily reduced to 2) you rascal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82264/discussion-between-mohamad-arafat-and-drew-pierce).

Comment: Hi Mohamad. Please open a new question about data as this question was long in scrolling to begin with plus about indexes

Comment: Hi Drew,
I've opened a new question.
This is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237242/mysql-view-with-left-join-shows-all-the-probability-of-records