# MYSQL View with LEFT JOIN shows all the probability of records

Tags: mysql, view, left-join

I am working on a view that joins multiple table. The data will be entered on separate table based on RepairID. The view will gather the data that is linking to the RepairID. My problem is after I enter the data, the view will show all the probability of the records output. Below are my code of view:

```
SELECT 
    `new`.`SRPartsID` AS `SRPartsID`,
    `new`.`RepairID` AS `RepairID`,
    `new`.`SRNo` AS `SRNo`,
    `new`.`DateReceived` AS `DateReceived`,
    `new`.`ShipmentDate` AS `ShipmentDate`,
    `tb1stdebug`.`FirstDebugTestingErrorCode` AS `FirstDebugTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb1stdebug`.`FirstDebugActionTaken` AS `FirstDebugActionTaken`,
    `tb1stdebug`.`FirstDebugComponentLocation` AS `FirstDebugComponentLocation`,
    `tb2nddebug`.`SecondDebugTestingErrorCode` AS `SecondDebugTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb2nddebug`.`SecondDebugActionTaken` AS `SecondDebugActionTaken`,
    `tb2nddebug`.`SecondDebugComponentLocation` AS `SecondDebugComponentLocation`,
    `tb3rddebug`.`ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode` AS `ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb3rddebug`.`ThirdDebugActionTaken` AS `ThirdDebugActionTaken`,
    `tb3rddebug`.`ThirdDebugComponentLocation` AS `ThirdDebugComponentLocation`,
    `tb1stfct`.`FirstFctTestingErrorCode` AS `FirstFctTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb1stfct`.`FirstFctActionTaken` AS `FirstFctActionTaken`,
    `tb1stfct`.`FirstFctComponentLocation` AS `FirstFctComponentLocation`,
    `tb2ndfct`.`SecondFctTestingErrorCode` AS `SecondFctTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb2ndfct`.`SecondFctActionTaken` AS `SecondFctActionTaken`,
    `tb2ndfct`.`SecondFctComponentLocation` AS `SecondFctComponentLocation`,
    `tb3rdfct`.`ThirdFctTestingErrorCode` AS `ThirdFctTestingErrorCode`,
    `tb3rdfct`.`ThirdFctActionTaken` AS `ThirdFctActionTaken`,
    `tb3rdfct`.`ThirdFctComponentLocation` AS `ThirdFctComponentLocation`
FROM
    ((((((`tbsrparts_new` `new`
    LEFT JOIN `tb1stdebug` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb1stdebug`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb2nddebug` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb2nddebug`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb3rddebug` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb3rddebug`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb1stfct` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb1stfct`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb2ndfct` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb2ndfct`.`RepairID`)))
    LEFT JOIN `tb3rdfct` ON ((`new`.`RepairID` = `tb3rdfct`.`RepairID`)))
ORDER BY `new`.`SRPartsID` DESC
```

This is my table structure

**tbsrparts_new**

```
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|             Field             |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SRPartsID                     | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                      | varchar(200)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| SRNo                          | varchar(200)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| DateReceived                  | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ShipmentDate                  | varchar(200)       | YES  |     | NULL    
+-------------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**tb1stdebug**

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|            Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| FirstDebugID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                    | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstDebugTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| FirstDebugActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstDebugComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**tb2nddebug**

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|            Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SecondDebugID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                     | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SecondDebugTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SecondDebugActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SecondDebugComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**tb3rddebug**

```
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|            Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ThirdDebugID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                    | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ThirdDebugActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ThirdDebugComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**tb1stfct**

```
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|           Field           |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| FirstFctID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                  | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstFctTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| FirstFctActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstFctComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**tb2ndfct**

```
+----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|           Field            |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SecondFctID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                   | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SecondFctTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| SecondFctActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| SecondFctComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**tb3rdfct**

```
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
|           Field           |        Type        | Null | Key | Default |     Extra      |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ThirdFctID                | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| RepairID                  | varchar(45)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ThirdFctTestingErrorCode  | varchar(500)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ThirdFctActionTaken       | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ThirdFctComponentLocation | varchar(500)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This is my sample data inserted to the db

**tbsrparts_new**

```
+-----------+----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
| SRPartsID | RepairID | SRNo  | DateReceived | ShipmentDate |
+-----------+----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
|     26050 |    26041 | test2 | 02,July,2015 | Pending      |
+-----------+----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
```

**tb1stdebug**

```
+--------------+----------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
| FirstDebugID | RepairID | FirstDebugTestingErrorCode | FirstDebugActionTaken | FirstDebugComponentLocation |
+--------------+----------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
|        26048 |    26041 | T00111                     | Touch Up              | -                           |
|        26049 |    26041 | T02222                     | Retest                | -                           |
|        26053 |    26041 | T08888                     | Touch Up              | -                           |
+--------------+----------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

**tb2nddebug**

```
+---------------+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+
| SecondDebugID | RepairID | SecondDebugTestingErrorCode | SecondDebugActionTaken | SecondDebugComponentLocation |
+---------------+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+
|            12 |    26041 | T03333                      | Touch Up               | -                            |
|            13 |    26041 | T04444                      | Retest                 | -                            |
|            14 |    26041 | T08888                      | Touch Up               | -                            |
+---------------+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+
```

**tb3rddebug**

```
+--------------+----------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
| ThirdDebugID | RepairID | ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode | ThirdDebugActionTaken | ThirdDebugComponentLocation |
+--------------+----------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
|           12 |    26041 | T03333                     | Touch Up              | -                           |
|           13 |    26041 | T04444                     | Retest                | -                           |
|           14 |    26041 | T08888                     | Touch Up              | -                           |
+--------------+----------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

**tb1stfct**

```
+------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| FirstFctID | RepairID | FirstFctTestingErrorCode | FirstFctActionTaken | FirstFctComponentLocation |
+------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
|      26052 |    26041 | T08888                   | Retest              | -                         |
+------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

**tb2ndfct**

```
+-------------+----------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
| SecondFctID | RepairID | SecondFctTestingErrorCode | SecondFctActionTaken | SecondFctComponentLocation |
+-------------+----------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
|           9 |    26041 | T08888                    | Touch Up             | -                          |
|          10 |    26041 | T88889                    | Retest               | -                          |
+-------------+----------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
```

**tb3rdfct**

```
+------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| ThirdFctID | RepairID | ThirdFctTestingErrorCode | ThirdFctActionTaken | ThirdFctComponentLocation |
+------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
|          7 |    26041 | T08888                   | Touch Up            | -                         |
+------------+----------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

The output on the view shows all the probability of the combination since some of the table has more than 1 records that referring to the same RepairID.Below are the output in image format. I cant paste the table because it reached the maximum characters.

[image: Output]

This is the output i want

```
+-------+---------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| SRNo  | DateReceived  | ShipmentDate | FirstDebugTestingErrorCode | FirstDebugActionTaken | FirstDebugComponentLocation | SecondDebugTestingErrorCode | SecondDebugActionTaken | SecondDebugComponentLocation | ThirdDebugTestingErrorCode | ThirdDebugActionTaken | ThirdDebugComponentLocation | FirstFctTestingErrorCode | FirstFctActionTaken | FirstFctComponentLocation | SecondFctTestingErrorCode | SecondFctActionTaken | SecondFctComponentLocation | ThirdFctTestingErrorCode | ThirdFctActionTaken | ThirdFctComponentLocation |
+-------+---------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| test2 | 2, July, 2015 | Pending      | T00111                     | Touch Up              | -                           | T03333                      | Touch Up               | -                            | T05555                     | Touch Up              | -                           | T08888                   | Retest              | -                         | T08888                    | Touch Up             | -                          | T08888                   | Touch Up            | -                         |
| test2 | 2, July, 2015 | Pending      | T02222                     | Retest                | -                           | T04444                      | Retest                 | -                            | T06666                     | Retest                | -                           | T08888                   | Retest              | -                         | T08889                    | Retest               | -                          | T08888                   | Touch Up            | -                         |
| test2 | 2, July, 2015 | Pending      | T08888                     | Touch Up              | -                           | T08888                      | Touch Up               | -                            | T08888                     | Touch Up              | -                           | T08888                   | Retest              | -                         | T08889                    | Retest               | -                          | T08888                   | Touch Up            | -                         |
+-------+---------------+--------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: This would be the expected behavior since you haven't specified how the joins should work other than 'RepairID'.  For instance, if you had just the 3 tables 'new', 'tb1stdebug', and 'tb2nddebug' - you haven't clarified what the correlation is between 'tb1stdebug' and 'tb2nddebug'.  As such, you'll get a cartesian product of these 2 tables until you do.

Comment: @PinnyM, The tables has no relationship. The only thing common in these table is RepairID.

Comment: Exactly, because there is no specific relationship, the JOINs will return every combination of rows where the RepairID matches.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure on how to define the specific relationship. I have also created the sqlfiddle : sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d155d/1. Appreciate if you can help.

Comment: Perhaps you should show your desired output to make things clearer

Comment: Hi @keongkenshih, I have edited the question with the output i want. Is there any way to get the output like it?

Comment: Sure - if you can explain why in your desired output FirstDebugTestingErrorCode `T00111` is considered a match for SecondDebugTestingErrorCode `T03333` but not `T04444`.  And why SecondFctTestingErrorCode `T08889` is being repeated on the 3rd row.  I suspect that RowNumber plays a role here, but you haven't clarified anything in this respect.  (And that also wouldn't explain the duplicate I mentioned above.)