# guaranteed fast response, expected row count for 1sec

Tags: mysql, performance

I am using MySQL 5.5 , my table have 6 columns with int ,varchar, datetime data type. I create index for the Id (int) column. If I want the query with condition base on Id column always keep the response time below than 1s. How many rows in my tables Btree index can adapt ?

Thanks

Comment: It will slow over time. Show table schemas and rowcounts, selects and joins so people can speculate on an Improved Question. Also don't have a Title as long as a river :)

Comment: Is there any statistic about my above question ? I just wants to estimate how many rows in my tables that the Btree can adapt ?

Comment: Yes there are statistics. You generate dummy data and publish those statistics based on what your unknown sql is. One sends sql thru `explain` and maybe gets better statistics because sql engine might be optimized.

Comment: The s.o. community rejoices with that unselfish sharing of statistics, maybe helps with optimization when question is improved, and showers Phao with points

Comment: Thanks Drew Pierce, but in my condition I can not to create a enough big tables to test with my question query. I hope some one have work with product big table data an show me the upper limit of Btree index performance.

Comment: You are a developer on your hardware

Comment: I have just 2 tables with 6 column, one hardisk, 32 GB RAM, 16 Cores CPU , query just one key but return many row.

Comment: A BTree can easily handle a billion rows.  And still get a "point query" in less than a second.  Surely you are doing something other than `SELECT ... WHERE id = (constant)`??

Answer (score 0):

MySql rarely take more than one second in respond one query as you con see here [Don't Click, Never!!!](http://we-love-php.blogspot.com/2012/07/mysql-or-mysqli-or-pdo.html) the real two problems are:

1. The loop structure that you use to process the reponse.
2. How much users queries at the same time

if many users request info simultaneusly, this can create lag in your database server (Many users refers to really MANY users, 100 in example is nothing). if you request data and fetch this in one array (example: mysqli_fetch_array in php) the processing time for this command extend the time needed to show the response in screen. if additionaly you process each column of the response with foreach loops, switch statement  etc... you response time will go to the sky.

Comment: If it is so rare why do we spend so much time dealing here with 800 second timeout nightmares

Comment: Sorry, english isn't my native language and i not understand your comment, please clarify this a little more ;)

Comment: All I know am this. Your english is better

Comment: I understand two odds:

1. Your comment was rhetorical.
2. Your database take actually 800 seconds or more in response your queries.

Comment: Here I just to estimate the ability of a Btree Index with my conditions, estimate help me soon to have a new solution when my database reach the number of rows that make the query response slower than 1s. Hope some have the real condition with big table and your response still adapt my request response time.

Comment: My comment was about your `rare` comment. It aint that rare

Comment: mmmmm, @Drew Pierce, finally i understand your comment, installed in a conventional server (2.4Ghz, 2Gb, 1Gb Bandwidth) the responses of the mysql server never take more of 1 second, i had work with large databases (1.000.000+ rows) and the queries never take more of 1 second, display its in the screen, is other history hahaha, PHAO THU if you use LIKE tatement to search, the lvls of your database (whit 1.000.000 of record) is 3 maximum, in databses of 10.000.000 or more records there is 4 lvls maximum, therefore 4 comparisons max, so the time still very low.

Comment: If you are searching by (=) values, is better to use HASH index. how i say above, the response time is affected for the server performance and the users quantity.

Comment: Jigs i am dragging you into the real world if it kills me

Comment: Here's one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016401/mysql-view-with-join-multiple-table-results-in-slow-query/31078304?noredirect=1#comment50476815_31078304

Comment: 726 seconds. At last check 726>1

Comment: Hahahaha, @DrewPierce malformed queries and views not count to mysql response, in this question we are the response time to singles queries due to the row count, the question that you show to me is processing time, not response time... And can be improved, i save this in favorites at night I give you a hand with that ;)

Comment: Response time and processing time is part of this question. Your help anywhere is appreciated